# Load inconsistent data in pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I am working with pymongo and am wanting to ensure that data saved can be loaded even if additional data elements have been added to the schema.

I have used this for classes that don't need to have the information processed before assigning it to class attributes:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, instance_id):
        #set default values
        self.database_id = instance_id
        self.myvar = 0

        #load values from database
        self.__load()

    def __load(self):
        data_dict = Collection.find_one({"_id":self.database_id})
        for key, attribute in data_dict.items():
            self.__setattr__(key,attribute)
```

However, in classes that I have to process the data from the database this doesn't work:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.database_id = None
        self.member_dict = {}

        self.load()

    def load(self):
        data_dict = Collection.find_one({"name":self.name})
        self.database_id = data_dict["_id"]
        for element in data_dict["element_list"]:
            self.process_element(element)
        for member_name, member_info in data_dict["member_class_dict"].items():
            self.member_dict[member_name] = MemberClass(member_info)

    def process_element(self, element):
        print("Do Stuff")
```

Two example use cases I have are:

1) List of strings the are used to set flags, this is done by calling a function with the string as the argument. (`def process_element` above)

2) A dictionary of dictionaries which are used to create a list of instances of a class. (`MemberClass(member_info)` above)

I tried creating properties to handle this but found that `__setattr__` doesn't look for properties.

I know I could redefine `__setattr__` to look for specific names but it is my understanding that this would slow down all set interactions with the class and I would prefer to avoid that.

I also know I could use a bunch of try/excepts to catch the errors but this would end up making the code very bulky.

I don't mind the load function being slowed down a bit for this but very much want to avoid anything that will slow down the class outside of loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that I came up with is to use the idea of changing the `__setattr__` method but instead to handle the exceptions in the load function instead of the `__setattr__`.

```
def load(self):
    data_dict = Collection.find_one({"name":self.name})

    for key, attribute in world_data.items():
        if key == "_id":
            self.database_id = attribute
        elif key == "element_list":
            for element in attribute:
                self.process_element(element)
        elif key == "member_class_dict":
            for member_name, member_info in attribute.items():
                self.member_dict[member_name] = MemberClass(member_info)
        else:
            self.__setattr__(key,attribute)
```

This provides all of the functionality of overriding the `__setattr__` method without slowing down any future calls to `__setattr__` outside of loading the class.